# Optimized Storage i.e Session Vs bean

Tags: jsp, session, javabeans, session-variables, storing-data

When i Use a request Dispatcher Object in My controller and forwarded the request response.
I got a null point error. So i had to save all my stuff i.e objects into session variables.
I am planning to use a Bean Instead of session. How is it better than session in terms of Safety and complexity.Also I know upto a certain level(amount of data) the session would not be able to handle. Which one is the most efficient ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are less secure as when the user logs in, the cookies are saved, which are easier to hack.